# How can I create a waveform image of an MP3 in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, mp3, package

Given an MP3 I would like to extract the waveform from the file into an image (.png)

Is there a package that can do what I need ?

Comment: Yes, there is a tool that does exactly that: http://www.tuned-project.org/audio-tools

Comment: @user1217953 - tuned audio tools link is dead, it seems to be in https://launchpad.net/tuned-audio-tools/+download (note, you'd need `libgee` and `gstreamer-1.0` to build); see also https://github.com/limikael/rendersound (note, you need a relatively new `libavcodec` to build it); see also [wav2png](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11067909/277826)

Answer (score 21):

Using `sox` and `gnuplot` you can create basic waveform images:

```bash
sox audio.mp3 audio.dat #create plaintext file of amplitude values
tail -n+3 audio.dat > audio_only.dat #remove comments

# write script file for gnuplot
echo set term png size 320,180 > audio.gpi #set output format
echo set output \"audio.png\" >> audio.gpi #set output file
echo plot \"audio_only.dat\" with lines >> audio.gpi #plot data

gnuplot audio.gpi #run script
```

[image]

To create something simpler/prettier, use the following GNU Plot file as a template (save it as **audio.gpi**):

```gnuplot
#set output format and size
set term png size 320,180

#set output file
set output "audio.png"

# set y range
set yr [-1:1]

# we want just the data
unset key
unset tics
unset border
set lmargin 0             
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0

# draw rectangle to change background color
set obj 1 rectangle behind from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgbcolor "#222222"

# draw data with foreground color
plot "audio_only.dat" with lines lt rgb 'white'
```

and just run:

```bash
sox audio.mp3 audio.dat #create plaintext file of amplitude values
tail -n+3 audio.dat > audio_only.dat #remove comments

gnuplot audio.gpi #run script
```

[image]

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5827100/188159) to a similar question that is more general regarding file format but less general in regards to software used.

Answer (score 8):

**FFmpeg `showwavespic`**

FFmpeg can do it in a single command as usual:

- tutorial on wiki at: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform
- documentation for the filter: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic

Sample command:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i in.flac -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x320:colors=black" \
  -frames:v 1 out.png
```

You can also set `colors` in RGB `colors=0x0088FF`: [Using hex colors with ffmpeg's showwaves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885460/using-hex-colors-with-ffmpegs-showwaves)

Sample test data of me saying "Hello my name is Ciro Santilli" with two identical stereo channels:

```
wget -O in.flac https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cirosantilli/media/d6e9e8d0b01bccef4958eb8b976c3b0a34870cd3/Hello_my_name_is_Ciro_Santilli.flac
```

Output:

[image]

**Background color**

The background is transparent by default, but:

- the Wiki teaches us how to add a image background: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform#Addingabackground
- [Overlay timelapse video on solid background colour using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986208/overlay-timelapse-video-on-solid-background-colour-using-ffmpeg) teaches us how to generate a solid color for an image

and so we reach:

```
ffmpeg -i in.flac -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x320 -filter_complex \
  "[0:a]showwavespic=s=640x320:colors=white[fg];[1:v][fg]overlay=format=auto" \
  -frames:v 1 out.png
```

Added to the Wiki now ;-)

For the uninitiated, that CLI creates a processing graph:

```
black background (1:v) ------------------------> overlay ----> out.png
                                                   ^
                                                   |
in.flac (0:a) ----> showwavespic ----> (fg) -------+
```

where e.g. the `overlay` filter takes two image inputs and produces the desired output, and `fg` is just a name assigned to an intermediate node.

[image]

**Split channels**

The tutorial also covers other options such as split channels with `-filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x480:colors=black:split_channels=1"`:

[image]

**gnuplot plot with axes**

OK, I'll admit it, FFmpeg can't do this alone (yet!). But the Wiki already provides a data export method to gnuplot that works:

```
ffmpeg -i in.flac -ac 1 -filter:a aresample=8000 -map 0:a -c:a pcm_s16le -f data - | \
  gnuplot -p -e "set terminal png size 640,360; set output 'out.png'; plot '<cat' binary filetype=bin format='%int16' endian=little array=1:0 with lines;"
```

[image]

**Video representations**

See: https://superuser.com/questions/843774/create-a-video-file-from-an-audio-file-and-add-visualizations-from-audio

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, FFmpeg 4.2.4.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a GUI environment you can use the [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) audio editor to load the mp3 and then use the print command to generate a pdf of the waveform.  Then convert the pdf to png.

Comment: The question is posted on Stack Overflow. Therefore I think it's a programming question. What you are offering is a workaround, that can only be done if you have a _user_ that will do it for every file manually. Not doing -1 because I lold ))

Comment: I was sincerely trying to be helpful (and amazed audacity could print).  Also, this: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=38341

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Although was looking to automate the process of creating a spectrogram (image) from and audio file (mp3). The link you sent looks real useful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this :

- find a tool to convert mp3 to PCM, ie binary data with one 8 or 16 bit value
  per sample. I guess mplayer can do that
- pipe the result to a utility converting binary data to an ascii
  representation of the numbers in decimal format
- use gnuplot to transform this list of value into a png graph.

And voilà, the power of piping between unix tools. Now Step 2 in this list might be optionnal if gnuplot is able to read it's data from a binary format.

Comment: Sounds like a real good idea. Will give this a shot and let you know how it goes. 
And yes gnuplot does accept a binary data file as its data source.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider audiowaveform from the BBC.

> audiowaveform is a C++ command-line application that generates waveform data from either MP3, WAV, or FLAC format audio files. Waveform data can be used to produce a visual rendering of the audio, similar in appearance to audio editing applications.
>
> Waveform data files are saved in either binary format (.dat) or JSON (.json). Given an input waveform data file, audiowaveform can also render the audio waveform as a PNG image at a given time offset and zoom level.
>
> The waveform data is produced from an input stereo audio signal by first combining the left and right channels to produce a mono signal. The next stage is to compute the minimum and maximum sample values over groups of N input samples (where N is controlled by the --zoom command-line option), such that each N input samples produces one pair of minimum and maxmimum points in the output.

https://github.com/bbcrd/audiowaveform

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard function in SoX (command line tool for sound, Windows & Linux)
Check the 'spectrogram' function on http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

"The spectrogram is rendered in a Portable Network Graphic (PNG) file, and shows time in the X-axis, frequency in the Y-axis, and audio signal magnitude in the Z-axis. Z-axis values are represented by the colour (or optionally the intensity) of the pixels in the X-Y plane. If the audio signal contains multiple channels then these are shown from top to bottom starting from channel 1 (which is the left channel for stereo audio)."

Comment: A spectrogram displays frequency domain information of the audio stream, a waveform displays time-domain information. They are vastly different ways to represent sound.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer of qubodup

```
# install stuff
apt install gnuplot
apt install sox
apt install libsox-fmt-mp3

#create plaintext file of amplitude values
sox sound.mp3 sound.dat

# run script saved on audio.gpi file
gnuplot audio.gpi
```

You can also comment the "set output ..." line in the configuration file and do

```
gnuplot audio.gpi > my_sound.png
```

The configuration file is audio.gpi in this case and inside it has

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set datafile commentschars ";"

set terminal png #size 800,400
set output "sound.png"

unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics

set key off

plot "sound.dat" with lines
```

Which produces images like the following

[image]

I wanted no axis, no legend, png (much smaller than svg).