# Gnuplot: How to plot multiple time series from a binary format

Tags: gnuplot

Would someone please elucidate the gnuplot binary format?

The goal is to plot two time series from a binary pipe as line graphs on the same graph. The series are float64's. I'm piping them in using something like:

```
plot "-" binary format="%float64" endian=big with lines
```

However, I don't understand what order the data should go in. In the above, I can specify `array=10`, and pipe in 10 numbers; this works. However, what about two series? And what if they are indexed differently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question may also be related: [Plotting 1D binary array (uint8) with multiple records in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472419/plotting-1d-binary-array-uint8-with-multiple-records-in-gnuplot)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for two series:

```
plot "-" binary format="%float64" record=10 endian=big with lines, 
     "-" binary format="%float32" record=20 endian=big with lines
```

I recommed you to use `record` instead of `array`, this way you can manually specify or operate the X axis value with the `using ($0*2):1` command.

If they are indexed differently, for example interlaced, there is no way to indicate that to gnuplot. Just copy to the pipe the information twice and ignore the non-usefull part with an `*`:

```
plot "-" binary format="%float64%*float32" record=20 endian=big with lines, 
     "-" binary format="%*float64%float32" record=20 endian=big with lines
```

Anyway, gnuplot does not allow to represent two graphs with the same input data, so the data must be copyed twice most of the times.

Hope that helps!