# Plotting 1D binary array (uint8) with multiple records in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I understand this question is similar to [Gnuplot: How to plot multiple time series from a binary format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441293/gnuplot-how-to-plot-multiple-time-series-from-a-binary-format/9878787#9878787); however I've already set up an example which is slightly different, so hope it's OK to post (self-answer follows).

I'm generating my binary data like this (see below for the `genbindata.pl` Perl script):

```
$ perl genbindata.pl > bin.dat
$ du -b bin.dat 
234 bin.dat
```

This binary file, `bin.dat` is formatted like this (first two rows are 1-based and 0-based index):

```
>|  1   2   3   4 |  5   6 ... 104 |105 106 ... 204 |205 206 ... 234
>|000 001 002 003 |004 005 ... 103 |104 105 ... 203 |204 205 ... 233
>| WW  WW  WW  WW | XX  XX ...  XX | YY  YY ...  YY | ZZ  ZZ ...  ZZ
```

... where `WW` are 4 bytes of signature; `XX` are 100 bytes of a sinusoid with values from 0 to 63; `YY` are 100 bytes of a cosine with values from 64 to 127; and `ZZ` are 30 bytes of random value; here considering a byte to be `uint8`.

**What I want to do**, is to use this `bin.dat` as-it-is (*that is, I wouldn't like to write scripts to parse the data, and output it in a more `gnuplot` friendly format*) - and plot the sine and cosine data, with separate color, on a single diagram.

I found [Binary general](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node103.html) section of the help (same in `gnuplot` terminal by typing `help binary general`), but have difficulties understanding it (*and couldn't find much more other info online*). So - after scavenging for (the few) examples online - I fire up `gnuplot` in terminal mode, and I'm trying the following `gnuplot` command:

`plot "bin.dat" binary skip=4 array=100x1:100x1 format='%uint8%uint8' origin=(0,0):(100,0) using 0:1 with lines`

... in hope that it means: "Skip the first four bytes, interpret the next as 100 bytes of 1D data (formatted as '%uint8', and origin at 0,0 after skip), followed by 100 bytes of 1D data (100 rows of one column, formatted as '%uint8', and origin at 100,0 after skip); and use pseudocolumn 0 (index of point) as x axis, and the first result from the arrays, to plot with lines"... unfortunately, it **doesn't** mean that - as nothing is plotted, and the command fails with "*Too many using specs for this style*".

Then I think - ok, if there is "too many `using`", then I'll just plot the `1` there:

```
    gnuplot> plot "bin.dat" binary skip=4 array=100x1:100x1 format='%uint8%uint8' origin=(0,0):(100,0) using 1 with lines
    Warning: empty y range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
```

This does in fact generate a plot - a single flat red line at the y=0.

So, given it complains about y range, I change the order of the origin arguments ((100,0) to (0,100)), and finally get a command that doesn't generate any message:

```
gnuplot> plot "bin.dat" binary skip=4 array=100x1:100x1 format='%uchar%uchar' origin=(0,0):(0,100) using 1 with lines
gnuplot>
```

... but it plots just a single tilted line:

[image: gnuplot-fail-1]

... nothing like the sinusoid I expect `:(`

So, my question is - how can I get `gnuplot` to plot the data that I want?

---

Here is `genbindata.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.10.1;
use warnings;
use strict;
use open IO => ':raw'; 

binmode(STDIN);
binmode(STDOUT);

my $signatur = "SIGN";
my @signature = unpack('C*', $signatur);

my (@ch1, @ch2) = ()x2;

# generate 100 samples of (co)sinusoid
for ( my $ix = 0; $ix < 100; $ix++ ) {
  my $val1 = 1 + sin($ix*2*3.14/100); # range: 0-2
  my $val2 = 1 + cos($ix*2*3.14/100); # range: 0-2
  my $ch1val = int($val1*32);
  my $ch2val = int($val2*32+64);
  push(@ch1, $ch1val);
  push(@ch2, $ch2val);
  #print STDERR "val[$ix]: $ch1val, $ch2val\n";
}

# generate 30 samples random
my @end = ();
for ( my $ix = 0; $ix < 30; $ix++ ) {
  my $val = int(128*rand() + 32);
  push(@end, $val);
  #~ print STDERR "val[$ix]: $val\n";
}

# concatenate arrays:
my @output = (@signature,@ch1,@ch2,@end);
my $sizarr = scalar(@output);
#~ print STDERR " ".." ";

# print output - uint8: "C"
my $outstr = pack("C*", @output);
my $lenstr = length($outstr);
#~ print STDERR "output size: $sizarr; output length: $lenstr\n";
print $outstr;

# end
```

Answer (score 13):

Well, there are some misconceptions in the question above; I'm using gnuplot 4.4 for this. First of, note how I've thought that the "`100x1`" in  "`array=100x1:100x1`" indicates dataset of 100 rows and 1 column - which would be identical to 1D array (the index being implied). However, that is **not** so; note the `help binary array` says:

> Note:  Gnuplot version 4.2 used the syntax array=128x128 rather than
>   array=(128,128). The older syntax is now deprecated, but may
>   still work [...]
>
> The coordinates will be generated by gnuplot.  A number must be specified
>   for each dimension of the array.  For example, `array=(10,20)` means the
>   underlying sampling structure is **two-dimensional** with 10 points along the
>   first (x) dimension [..]

Thus, even if "`100x1`" *conceptually* may be identical to 1D array - just by writing it like that, I've indicated a 2D data to `gnuplot` (*e.g. an image; which, I'd expect, is instantiated differently than a 1D array of 100 elements, internally in `gnuplot`*). So, instead I should have written "`array=(100):(100)`". Note that parenthesis can in principle be dropped for 1D, so "`array=100:100`" would have been OK too - except in the case of using `-1` (read until the end of file) as dimension; then a parenthesis has to be used, else error occurs.

Then, there is the problem of multiple records. I could find very few references to these "multiple records" in `gnuplot` - there was [Binary syntax reduction [Was: Lengthy discussion...] (gnuplot.devel)](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.graphics.gnuplot.devel/1579):

> How about tossing out the multiple records per file feature. If there is more than one big data set to plot, just create multiple files.

I, for one, am glad they kept the multiple records feature - but I sure wish it was explained better. Another comment I found in [Gnuplot, Plot with sum of datasets](http://www.graphicsgroups.com/9-gnuplot/9bc8bdf3399b94f3.htm):

> ... gnuplot (3.6, that is) can plot combinations of data on a single record, but cannot combine data from multiple records, much less multiple datasets.
>
> You'll have to write a preprocessor that does these calculations.

The `help binary array` says just:

> A colon can be used to separate the dimensions for multiple records.
>   For example, `array=25:35` indicates there are two one-dimensional records in
>   the file.

This made me think that if I specify "`array=(100):(100)`" as two (multiple) records, I could "access" these records in a `using 0:1` and `using 0:2` statements respectively (using the pseudocolumn 0 to index their data). Turns out, that is **not** the case - it seems to me that the only facility such a specification of multiple records allows for, is the ability to control them via `origin` and/or `skip` parameters, but only *within a single plot*.

Talking of records, note also there is `help binary record`:

> This keyword serves the same function as `array`, having the same syntax.
>   However, `record` causes gnuplot to not generate coordinate information.
>   This is for the case where such information may be included in one of the
>   columns of the binary data file.

This doesn't tell me much - but I think it means that, in principle, one *should* specify pseudocolumn 0 to index the data if using `record`; but should *not* do that for `array`. Thus, the following two commands are equivalent:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(50) format='%uint8' using 1 with lines

plot "bin.dat" binary record=(50) format='%uint8' using 0:1 with lines`

... which gets the first 50 samples as the first (and only) record of 1-D data, with its (only) column of data formatted as `uint8` - and plots it:

[image: gnuplot-50-samps]

Note that

- doing `record` with just `using 1` will generate the same image as the above equivalent commands;
- but doing `array` with `0:1` will generate the line from the question OP!

It's a shame, that there doesn't seem to be an apparent way to debug the structures behind the "column identifiers" such as `1` in `using 1`, so as to confirm this one way or another; but I think the above means that:

- in `record`, the `1` describes a 1-column (50x1) dataset - thus it can be coupled with another 1-column index
- in `array`, the `1` actually describes a 2-column (50x2) dataset, where the first column is index - which is why when it is coupled with the another index (pseudocolumn 0), a line is generated (<sup>because the index pseudocolumn couples with the first column from `1`, which is also an index - that is, a list of monotonically rising (or falling) integers</sup>)

Then, note the `format` parameter - `help binary format` states:

> [...]  For example, `format="%uchar%int%float"`
>   associates an unsigned character with the first using column, an int with the
>   second column and a float with the third column. [...]

Now, this made me think that if I want to work with two 1-D multiple records, I'd have to use something like this:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(50):(50) format='%uint8%uint8' using 1 with lines`

... which generates:

[image: gnuplot-2rec-50-samps-resamp]

It's immediately obvious that the cosine part overlapping the sine is somehow wrong; but even more interesting is that the diagram shows the entire period of these functions in only 50 samples - while we have explicitly generated the data, so both the sine and cosine have a period of 100 samples! Ergo, the data is somehow resampled - and it turns out, the problem is with `format`.

By specifying "`array=(50):(50)`", we specify *two* (multiple) records which are **1-D**, and thus have one (and only) column each. However, the "`format='%uint8%uint8'`" does **not** refer to a format for each column of the two records - it apparently refers to a second *dimension*; and given that our two records are 1D, `gnuplot` simply takes away every other sample from the records.

Therefore, we can just specify a single "`format='%uint8'`" in our plot command:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(50):(50) format='%uint8' using 1 with lines`

... and get only half a period in 50 samples:

[image: gnuplot-2rec-50-samps]

... as expected. But that still doesn't solve the overlap between the records.

Here it is important to remember, that the multiple records seem always to be attributable to one and the same plot. The offset can then be regulated with the `origin` parameter; `help binary keywords origin` states:

> To position the array somewhere else on the graph, the `origin` keyword directs
>   gnuplot to position the lower left point of the array at a point specified by a
>   tuple.  The tuple should be a double for `plot` and a triple for `splot`.

So, we can do something like this:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(50):(50) format='%uint8' origin=(0,0):(50,0) using 1 with lines`

... which we can interpret as: get two *consecutive* 1D records, where their only dimension/column is formatted as `uint8` - and offset/move the first record by (0,0) on the plot, and the second by (50,0) (50 units in the +x direction) on the plot. We would expect now that the two records will be concatenated, and indeed:

[image: gnuplot-2rec-50-samps-conc]

... we can now observe what we would expect to be the first 100 samples of the data.

This about the records being "part of the same plot" can be more easily seen, if we just displace the second record for a bit (say, 10 units left) from the previously matched position:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(50):(50) format='%uint8' origin=(0,0):(40,0) using 1 with lines`

... while plotting with lines:

[image: gnuplot-2rec-50-samps-disp]

It's immediately visible this is not a function anymore, and what effect the origin offsetting has had.

That being said, we can now plot the entire data, by specifying all records in it, and their offsets, explicitly:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(4):(100):(100):(30) format='%uint8' origin=(0,0):(4,0):(104,0):(204,0) using 1 with lines`

... generates, as expected, the four records concatenated - recreating the entire dataset:

[image: gnuplot-4rec-all]

Note:

- Using `array=(4):(100):(100):(-1)` (for read to end) generates the same image
- Using `origin=(0,0):(4,0):(104,0)` (leave out last) with four records in `array`, causes the last 30 bytes to overlap from the beginning
- Using `array=(4):(100):(100)` (leave out last) makes the last 30 bytes disappear from plot (with either three or four records in origin)

Finally, let's look at the skip parameter. The `help binary skip` states:

> [...] For instance, if the
>   file contains a 1024 byte header before the start of the data region you would
>   probably want to use
>         plot '<file_name>' binary skip=1024 ...

This could be slightly misleading, since *both* of these commands:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(100) format='%uint8' using 1 with lines

plot "bin.dat" binary skip=4 array=(100) format='%uint8' using 1 with lines`

... generate the same plot:

[image: gnuplot-1rec-nooffs]

... where *no* skip is visible; however if we move the `skip=4` at end of keyword list (before `using`), the command becomes:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(100) format='%uint8' skip=4  using 1 with lines`

... and generates:

[image: gnuplot-1rec-offs]

... where a skip is, indeed, visible.

Note also from `help binary skip`:

> If there are multiple records in the file, you may specify a leading offset for
>   each. For example, to skip 512 bytes before the 1st record and 256 bytes before
>   the second and third records
>         plot <file_name> binary record=356:356:356 skip=512:256:256 ...

Let's just illustrate that - the below command:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(100):(100) format='%uint8' origin=(0,0):(100,0) skip=4 using 1 with lines`

... has two 1-D records (*we have to add `origin` to offset, else the records will again overlap*), but only one skip - which basically moves the whole sequence left by four units:

[image: gnuplot-2rec-skip]

If we now address the both fields in skip, as in the command:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(100):(100) format='%uint8' origin=(0,0):(100,0) skip=4:20 using 1 with lines`

... we can notice on the output:

[image: gnuplot-2rec-2skip]

... that the second record has been moved left by 20 units - and to make up for the lost 20 units at end, the remainder of the data from the, otherwise, next record (which is not addressed in the plot command).

Now we can go back to the original question - to "plot the sine and cosine data, with separate color, on a single diagram".

Before that, let's note that with two data "functions" per plot it gets easier to see that the `origin` parameter actually moves records on the plot; for instance, this command:

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(100) format='%uint8' origin=(4,0) using 1 with lines, \

"" binary array=(100) format='%uint8' origin=(104,0) using 1 with lines`

... results with:

[image: gnuplot-1rec-2func]

... where the *same* first 100 samples of data, are rendered on two different places in the plot (and with different colors).

After all the above, it is clear that: trying to "parse" and "split" the data - by using, say, `array=(4):(100):(100):(30)`  - into "records", will not help us much with having *two* data "functions" per plot (as implied by separate colors); only with a single data "function".

That is, for two data functions case, we can only specify: a single 1D record and its length in `array`; its (only) column's format; and an offset via `skip` - per data "function":

`plot "bin.dat" binary array=(100) format='%uint8' skip=4 using 1 with lines, \

"" binary array=(100) format='%uint8' skip=104 using 1 with lines`

... in order to get the desired rendering:

[image: gnuplot-1rec-2func]

As a final note - we can obtain the exact same diagram, by replacing `binary array` with `binary record` - except instead of `using 1`, we should write `using 0:1`:

`plot "bin.dat" binary record=(100) format='%uint8' skip=4 using 0:1 with lines, \
"" binary record=(100) format='%uint8' skip=104 using 0:1 with lines`

... even if in this particular case, `using 1` will work as well.

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!