# Gnuplot: binary plotting two 1D records against eachother

Tags: gnuplot, binary-data

I want to plot a single curve of data values versus time values, both of which come from a binary file. Both of these sets (data and time) are stored as 59, 4-byte floats. The data values are found first by skipping 52192 bytes into the file, then reading the next 59 values. The time values are stored similarly at 181676 bytes from the beginning of the file in a set of 59, 4-byte floats.

I'm able to plot each of these sets by themselves against the coordinate number, but I'm not able to plot the data versus the time. Here are the two lines that work as I would expect:

```
plot 'file.bin' binary endian=big record=59 skip=52192 using 1 title "data-1" with lines
plot 'file.bin' binary endian=big record=59 skip=181676 using 1 title "time-1" with lines
```

Here is how I'm trying to plot data-1 versus time-1 (the 129248 skip value is 181676-52192+4(59)):

```
plot 'file.bin' binary endian=big record=59:59 skip=52192:129248 using 2:1 title "data vs time" with lines
```

However, this seems to concatenate the two records into the 1 column, rather than storing the first record in column 1 and the second in column 2. I'm not sure how to prevent this concatenation.

I've read [Plotting 1D binary array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472419/plotting-1d-binary-array-uint8-with-multiple-records-in-gnuplot), but it ultimately plots against the coordinate values instead of plotting the first record against the second.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the data and then pasting the first set onto column 1 of another file and the second set onto column 2? You can even export the data with the gnuplot `set table` command twice (once per data set) and then use the bash command `paste` to generate the file with the right columnar format.

Comment: With `record=59:59` you indicate, that you have two records, each with `59` points. To have a two-dimensional record, you must use `record=(2,59)`. But I don't know, if in this case the `skip=52192:129248` works as expected. Maybe you must use `record=(2,129484) skip=52192 every ::58` possibly with `transpose`?! Thats only guessing as I don't have a data file for testing...