# Overlay timelapse video on solid background colour using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a load of screenshots of a homepage that are named `homescreen000001.png`, `homescreen000002.png`, etc and I'm trying to create a time-lapse video of these images using ffmpeg.

I've got it working in general when I run the following:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 \
       -i ~/Desktop/homescreen%06d.png \
       -r 0.5 \
       -s 1440x900 \ 
       -b:v 1M \
       -vcodec libx264 \ 
       -pix_fmt yuv420p \
       ~/Desktop/timelapse.mp4
```

However, it turns out that some of the images have transparent backgrounds so the background is showing up as black on those images.

I'd like a white background so I've been trying to set that up using ffmpeg as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 \
       -loop 1 \
       -i ~/Desktop/whitebg.png \
       -i ~/Desktop/homescreen%06d.png \
       -filter_complex overlay \ 
       -r 0.5 \
       -s 1440x900 \ 
       -b:v 1M \
       -vcodec libx264 \ 
       -pix_fmt yuv420p \
       ~/Desktop/timelapse.mp4
```

Here `whitebg.png` is 2px x 2px png with a white background, and that's it.

This ffmpeg command produces a really tiny (in file size) video that's just a white background.

Can anyone explain how I can overlay the images as a time-lapse video over a white background using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [color filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) as a background:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1920x1080:r=24 -framerate 24 -i input_%04d.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

Also see:

- [image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1)
- [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay)
- [How to position overlay with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918907/how-to-add-transparent-watermark-in-center-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg/10920872#10920872)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the transparent pixels with white ones using ImageMagick like this:

```
convert in.png -alpha off out.png
```

or for a whole directory (with output files in a subdirectory called `output`) like this:

```
mkdir output
for i in *.png; do
   convert "$i" -alpha off output/"$i"
done
```

Please make a backup first!

ImageMagick is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org) though it is already installed on many Linux distros.

Comment: While I like the general idea, this command does not produce white backgrounds. At least not anymore. Use the following instead:
`convert "$i" -background white -alpha remove -alpha off output/"$i"`
Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437562/3821986).